# ECONNREFUSED: Connection refused. Why? All other tests are passing

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mocha.js

I'm working with node/express/mongo and trying to run a test to find posts with a particular id.

This is my route:

```
app.get('/api/posts/:id', PostController.getPost);
```

This is the controller:

```
   getPost(req, res, next) {
    const postId = req.params.id;

    Post.findById({ _id: postId })
      .then(user => res.send(user))
      .catch(next);
  },
```

And this is the test:

```
describe('Post Controller', () => {
  it('find a post with a particular id', (done) => {
    const post = new Post({
      text: 'This is a post',
      voteCount: 0,
      commentCount: 0,
      createdAt: 0,
      expiresAt: 0
    });

    post.save().then(() => {
      console.log(post._id);
      request(app)
        .get(`api/posts/${post._id}`)
        .set('Accept', 'application/json')
        .expect(200)
        .end((err, res) => {
          console.log(res);
          if (err) return done(err);
          //assert(response.body.obj.firstName === 'Matt');
          done();
        });
    });
  });
```

The `post._id` is being console logged just fine.

The response is just logging as `null`.

`return done(err)` is what's coming back with `Error: ECONNREFUSED: Connection refused`

I know the route is working as it's coming through just fine on `postman`. Any idea why it might be failing the test?

All my other test are running just fine, such as this one:

```
it('POST to /api/posts creates a new post', done => {
    Post.count().then(count => {
      request(app)
        .post('/api/posts')
        .send({
          text: 'This is a post',
          voteCount: 0,
          commentCount: 0,
          createdAt: 0,
      expiresAt: 0
    })
    .end(() => {
      Post.count().then(newCount => {
        assert(count + 1 === newCount);
        done();
      });
    });
});
```

});

Would appreciate some help, please!

Answer (score 5):

Fixed, missed out the `/` in: `.get(`api/posts/${post._id}`)`

Answer (score 0):

check your get request, you're using :ud but your params are req.params.id

Comment: sorry, no that's not it :(. I copy and pasted the wrong code.